# Remove STRING before / character MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a column which contains data like

```
thumb/RANDOM_STRING.JPG
thumb/cat/RANDOM_STRING.JPG
thumb/test/again/RANDOM_STRING.JPG
```

I want to contain only the Image name. And want to DELETE every word before `/` character.

Here is what I have tried but it does not work

```
   UPDATE wsr_jshopping_products
   SET product_full_image =
     REPLACE(product_full_image,'thumb//', '');
```

Comment: Are you saying you just want to remove the text before and including the first `/` or do you only want the file name from each row?

Comment: I only want filename ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want the filename to remain use:

```
UPDATE wsr_jshopping_products 
      SET product_full_image = REVERSE(
                                 SUBSTRING(
                                   REVERSE(product_full_image),1,
                                           LOCATE('/',REVERSE(product_full_image))-1))
```

Comment: echo "You are a HERO! Thanks";